# Mixpanel push notification not working for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, mixpanel

I have successfully integrate Mixpanel into my iOS app. I have also set following for push notification:

1) $ios_device with valid device push token value.

2) APNS certificate.

3) A valid selection of criteria that is returning desire user with fresh push token.

I have also tried to send push from http://pushtry.com/ and I received push notification from pushtry.com. So my certificate and push token is valid. But I can't get push notification from Mixpanel.

If I looking into 'Messages' section it shows 0 (Zero) sent

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. Mixpanel has changed it's pricing structure. So Messages (Push notification) will not come in starter plan. Have to upgrade with Growth or Enterprise plan.

Here is the pricing: https://mixpanel.com/pricing/